# Integrate ceiling fixture into Hue system

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have an antique chandelier that I've wired directly into the ceiling, and I'd like to integrate it into my hue system. Hue makes chandelier bulbs, but I really want to use filament bulbs, which Philips does not make in chandelier bulb size.

The only option I am aware of for controlling non-hue bulbs with the hue system is the smart wall plug, which is designed for a plug-in outlet. I have considered terminating the chandelier cable with a standard wall plug, and then wiring the Hue smart plug into the ceiling via the exposed wires. I have no idea how good or bad an idea this might be. Does this in any way sound like a reasonable approach? Are their other approaches to allow a ceiling fixture to be controlled by the Hue?

Thank you.

Comment: why not use a switch? https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/explore-hue/works-with/smart-switches

Comment: My understanding is that the these smart switches can only control smart bulbs. If there were a smart switch that integrate with my Hue system AND control non-smart regular bulbs the same way a traditional dimmer switch works, that would be a good solution.

Comment: you seem to be right. Other smart switches act like, well, switches. Do you have a hub? Many can control several brands of hardware, though Hue often needs a "bridge" to connect. Still, that would allow you to use a cheap say, zigbee, switch that dim regular bulbs and can interact with your hue system as well.

Comment: I have a Hue hub, but unfortunately none of the zigbee switches I see on Amazon are compatible with Hue hubs.

Comment: @dandavis It looks like this one might do the trick: https://www.amazon.com/110-240V-compatible-SmartThings-Lightify-Automation/dp/B07GSJMNX1/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=smart+light+switch+hue+compatible&qid=1616371727&sr=8-9

Answer (score 1):

> and then wiring the Hue smart plug into the ceiling via the exposed
> wires.

What?, Exposed wires, NO.

You would have to have an outlet with the Hue smart plug installed and then plug the modified chandelier wire into the Hue smart outlet. That will only turn it off and on, not control brightness, tone and color like with the Hue bulbs.

> The only option I am aware of

How about their [smart dimmer switch](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-dimmer-switch--latest-model-/046677562779)?

They DO have a E12 base [candelabra bulb](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-white-and-color-ambiance-single-bulb-e12/046677556969).

You could use an [E12 to E26 adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B5KJDK9)  and use their [filament smart bulbs](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-white-filament-1-pack-g25-e26-filament-globe/046677551797)

Or a [White and color](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-white-and-color-ambiance-1-pack-e26/046677548483) E26 base bulb in the E12 to E26 adaptor.

[Philips Hue](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us)

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I have the e12 candelabra bulbs, and unfortunately really want to use a filament bulb here. I hadn't considered using the adapter, but I think the e26 is just too big for the fixture.